# Python word count (2 files that contains words) (1 file for word count) ( last file to write inside him word+count)

Tags: python, file, count, cpu-word

2 txt files that contain words (like lyrics for example)

1 txt file that contain the words I want to count in those 2 files^

1 txt file that will contain the words + count

```
file1 = open(r'E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\file1.txt','r')
file2 = open(r'E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\file2.txt','r')
file3 = open(r'E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\words.txt','r')
file4 = open(r'E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\wordsInFiles.txt','w')

for word in file3:
    word = word.strip("\n")
    counter = 0
    counter2 = 0
    for line in file1:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            w = w.strip()
            if(w == word):
                counter += 1
    file1.seek(0,0)
    for line in file2:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            w = w.strip()
            if(w == word):
                counter2 += 1
    file4.write(word + " " + str(counter) + "\n")
    file4.write(word + " " + str(counter2) + "\n")
    file2.seek(0,0)

file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
file4.close()
```

It duplicates the words for me, also counting is incorrect.

thanks for whoever help

Comment: Your code seems to be reading files 1 & 2 for each word in file3.  Unless file3 only has a couple of words this seems very inefficient.

Comment: Your counter is inccorect because `words = line.split();
        for w in words:` words is words on a line, but w are the letters in a word.

Comment: @DarrylG thanks for your response,
I am sorry for being ignorant i am kind of a beginner, I didn't quiet understand whats wrong with the counter and this for,
also in the file 3(words) i have  around 8 words.

Comment: @idanhalf--no problem.  Take a look at my answer where I attempted to solve your major issues.

Comment: don't do `file.open()` and `file.close()` use `filename.open()` in a `with` block so you don't have to think about calling `.close` if there's an error in your program and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

The OP code has the following issues.

(1) It checking letters rather than words with the following code lines:

```
for line in file2:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            w = w.strip()
            if(w == word):
```

(2) Loops through the file1 & file2 for each word (very inefficient).

**Code Refactored due to the above issues**

```
from collections import Counter
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
import string

# Utility Functions
def string_to_words(s):
  " Convert string to lower case words without puntuation "
  # Remove punctuation, lower case and split on space
  # Using remove punctuation code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string
  return s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower().split()

def update_count(s, valid_words, cnt = None):
  " count words in string "
  if s:
    if cnt == None:
      cnt = Counter()
    # Use generator (rather than list comprehension) to update counter i.e. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators
    cnt.update(word for word in string_to_words(s) if word in include_words)
  return cnt

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Main Code Body
  with open(r'words.txt','r') as file3:
  # Get set of cords that we want to include
  # Use set since this is much quicker than a list to see if the is in words
  # Use OrderedSet (rather than set) since this preserves the order of items
  # added which allows outputting in the same order as words in file words.txt
    include_words = OrderedSet()
    for line in file3:
      include_words.update(string_to_words(line.rstrip()))

  with open(r'file1.txt','r') as file1:
    cnt1 = None
    for line in file1:
      cnt1 = update_count(line.rstrip(), include_words, cnt1)

  with open(r'file2.txt','r') as file2:
    cnt2 = None
    for line in file2:
      cnt2 = update_count(line.rstrip(), include_words, cnt2)

  with open(r'wordsInFiles.txt','w') as file4:
    for word in include_words:
      file4.write(f'{word} {cnt1[word]}\n')
      file4.write(f'{word} {cnt2[word]}\n')
```

**Example Usage**

file1.txt

> There are five known copies of the speech in Lincoln's handwriting,
>   each with a slightly different text, and named for the people who
>   first received them: Nicolay, Hay, Everett, Bancroft and Bliss. Two
>   copies apparently were written before delivering the speech, one of
>   which probably was the reading copy.

file2.txt

> When shall we three meet again
>       In thunder, lightning, or in rain?
>
> ```
> When the hurlyburly's done,
> When the battle's lost and won.
>
> That will be ere the set of sun.
> ```

words.txt (allows multiple words per line, ignores blank lines and punctuation)

> ```
> There are 
> five known copies
>
> When the 
> hurlyburly's done
> When the battle's lost and won
> ```

wordsinfile.txt

```
there 1
there 0
are 1
are 0
five 1
five 0
known 1
known 0
copies 2
copies 0
when 0
when 3
the 4
the 3
hurlyburlys 0
hurlyburlys 1
done 0
done 1
battles 0
battles 1
lost 0
lost 1
and 2
and 1
won 0
won 1
```

Comment: I don't think you need to pass a list to Counter, a generator expression is fine, you can just remove the `[]`. You should mention that OrderedSet is not in the Python standard library.

Comment: @Bons--Agree.  I just used a list to reduce the number of things for the newbie to learn in understanding the refactoring.

Comment: @bons--switched to a generator with a pointer to an explanation for OP.

Answer (score 0):

1) Count all the words in all the files

2) Look at the file containing the words you're interested in and look up each word in the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object you got from step 1

```py
from collections import Counter

input_filenames = [
    r"E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\file1.txt",
    r"E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\file2.txt",
]
file_with_words_youre_interested_in = r"E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\file3.txt"
output_filename = r"E:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\python\wordsInFiles.txt"


# A generator that yields all the words in a file one by one
def get_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield from line.split()


filename_to_word_count = {
    filename: Counter(get_words(filename)) for filename in input_filenames
}

with open(file_with_words_youre_interested_in) as f:
    words_to_count = f.read().splitlines()

with open(output_filename, "w") as f:
    for word_to_count in words_to_count:
        for filename in input_filenames:
            f.write(f"{word_to_count} {filename_to_word_count[filename][word_to_count]}\n")
```

Comment: `line.split()` gives the same result as `line.strip().split()`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski rookie mistake, thanks. I fixed it